# How to make html parsing more performatic using python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I'm writing a python script to parse a html file that contains a table. This is an example of the file I want to parse:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="3080">
<tr>
<th width="50"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 1</font></small></th>
<th width="130" height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 2</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 3</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 4</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 5</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 6</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 7</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 8</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 9</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 10</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 11</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 12</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 13</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 14</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 15</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 16</font></small></th>
<th width="60"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 17</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 18</font></small></th>
<th width="80" height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 19</font></small></th>
<th width="95" height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 20</font></small></th>
<th width="95" height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 21</font></small></th>
<th width="80" height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 22>/font></small></th>
<th width="80" height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 23</font></small></th>
<th width="80" height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 24</font></small></th>
<th width="80" height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 25</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 26</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 27</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 28</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 29</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 30</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 31</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 32</font></small></th>
<th width="80"  height="20" bgcolor="#A55592"><small><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Header 33</font></small></th>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor=#D5BCCD>
<td rowspan="5">1</td>
<td rowspan="5">01/02/2016</td>
<td rowspan="5">18</td>
<td rowspan="5">20</td>
<td rowspan="5">25</td>
<td rowspan="5">23</td>
<td rowspan="5">10</td>
<td rowspan="5">11</td>
<td rowspan="5">24</td>
<td rowspan="5">14</td>
<td rowspan="5">06</td>
<td rowspan="5">02</td>
<td rowspan="5">13</td>
<td rowspan="5">09</td>
<td rowspan="5">05</td>
<td rowspan="5">16</td>
<td rowspan="5">03</td>
<td rowspan="5">Next value indicates number of rows to skip</td>
<td rowspan="5">5</td>
<td></td>
<td>XA</td>
<td rowspan="5">15</td>
<td rowspan="5">46</td>
<td rowspan="5">48</td>
<td rowspan="5">25</td>
<td rowspan="5">49</td>
<td rowspan="5">68</td>
<td rowspan="5">10</td>
<td rowspan="5">40</td>
<td rowspan="5">20</td>
<td rowspan="5">000</td>
<td rowspan="5">000</td>
<td rowspan="5">000</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor=#D5BCCD><td></td><td>XB</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#D5BCCD><td></td><td>XC</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#D5BCCD><td></td><td>XD</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#D5BCCD><td></td><td>XE</td></tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="1">2</td>
<td rowspan="1">02/02/2016</td>
<td rowspan="1">23</td>
<td rowspan="1">15</td>
<td rowspan="1">05</td>
<td rowspan="1">04</td>
<td rowspan="1">12</td>
<td rowspan="1">16</td>
<td rowspan="1">20</td>
<td rowspan="1">06</td>
<td rowspan="1">11</td>
<td rowspan="1">19</td>
<td rowspan="1">24</td>
<td rowspan="1">01</td>
<td rowspan="1">09</td>
<td rowspan="1">13</td>
<td rowspan="1">07</td>
<td rowspan="1">Next value indicates number of rows to skip</td>
<td rowspan="1">1</td>
<td></td>
<td>XA</td>
<td rowspan="1">184</td>
<td rowspan="1">6232</td>
<td rowspan="1">81252</td>
<td rowspan="1">478188</td>
<td rowspan="1">596.323,70</td>
<td rowspan="1">1.388,95</td>
<td rowspan="1">10,00</td>
<td rowspan="1">4,00</td>
<td rowspan="1">2,00</td>
<td rowspan="1">0,00</td>
<td rowspan="1">0,00</td>
<td rowspan="1">0,00</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor=#D5BCCD>
<td rowspan="5">3</td>
<td rowspan="5">04/02/2016</td>
<td rowspan="5">18</td>
<td rowspan="5">20</td>
<td rowspan="5">25</td>
<td rowspan="5">23</td>
<td rowspan="5">10</td>
<td rowspan="5">11</td>
<td rowspan="5">24</td>
<td rowspan="5">14</td>
<td rowspan="5">06</td>
<td rowspan="5">02</td>
<td rowspan="5">13</td>
<td rowspan="5">09</td>
<td rowspan="5">05</td>
<td rowspan="5">16</td>
<td rowspan="5">03</td>
<td rowspan="5">Next value indicates number of rows to skip</td>
<td rowspan="5">2</td>
<td></td>
<td>XA</td>
<td rowspan="5">15</td>
<td rowspan="5">46</td>
<td rowspan="5">48</td>
<td rowspan="5">25</td>
<td rowspan="5">49</td>
<td rowspan="5">68</td>
<td rowspan="5">10</td>
<td rowspan="5">40</td>
<td rowspan="5">20</td>
<td rowspan="5">000</td>
<td rowspan="5">000</td>
<td rowspan="5">000</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor=#D5BCCD><td></td><td>XB</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is the script I wrote to parse it:

```
# Parse the data
soup = BeautifulSoup(file(result_file))
table = soup.find('table')

# The first tr contains the field names.
headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('tr').find_all('th')]
important_headings = headings[:19]

all_tr = table.find_all('tr')
count = 1
data_sets = []
while count < len(all_tr):
    date_results = all_tr[count].find_all('td')
    skip_rows = int(date_results[18].get_text())
    count += skip_rows
    data_set = zip(important_headings, (td.get_text() for td in date_results[:19]))
    data_sets.append(data_set)

# Write the csv file
with open(csv_file, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data_sets)
```

It works but it takes around 30 milliseconds to parse 7 rows. The table on the real html file has around 1300 rows so it is going to take a while to parse it. If it does, because usually the process crashes before it finishes.

How can I make it perform better?

UPDATE (profiling information):

This is the time spent on each part of the algorithm:

- Finished finding table. Took 32.11s to complete.
- Finished finding all tr in the file. Took 103.414059ms to complete.

while Loop part

- Finished finding all td inside tr. Took 0.142097ms to complete.
- Finished getting skip rows. Took 0.020027ms to complete.
- Finished zipping. Took 0.100851ms to complete.
- Finished appending. Took 0.001907ms to complete.

Comment: did you try to profile it in order to understand where it spends most of the time?

Comment: What crash do you get? You can reduce memory usage by skipping the `data_sets` list and writing the csv file as you go.

Comment: @MaxU it spend the most time trying to find the 'table' tag. All the other operations are really fast but the problem is that it runs in a huge loop.

Comment: @tdelaney python simply exits silent. probably by memory usage as you mentioned. I will change it to write directly to the file. But it won't speed thinks up, right?!

Comment: @MaxU profiling data included.

Comment: On my slow laptop, changing parsers (`from lxml.etree import BeautifulSoup`) reduced runtime from 552 ms to 185ms. Since that includes python exec + module load time, that is quite significant.

Comment: Reducing memory footprint doesn't make a big difference until the system has to work to find more RAM, so it will depend on you system and its load.

Comment: Your csv writing will fail because you are trying to write tuples. It raises an error which you should see if you are running from the command line. Instead of the `zip` thing where you add the headers to each row, try `data_sets.append(list(td.get_text() for td in date_results[:19]))`. At 1300 rows, the script should run in about 6 seconds.

Comment: That is a good catch @tdelaney. I will check it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Try using python bindings of native C/C++ parsing libraries, e.g. [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/python.html) (this will obviously require to step off a bit from beautifulsoup convenience).

Comment: lxml integrates with beautifulsoup... [see this](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html)

Comment: You're right, it even does that by default, as [documentation states](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#specifying-the-parser-to-use).

Comment: I've changed it to use lxml and it seem there is no effect :(

Comment: This is how I changed BeautifulSoup to use lxml. `BeautifulSoup(doc, 'lxml')` is that the correct way of doing it @tdelaney?

Comment: yes, I typed it in wrong. After running each 10 times, the numbers got closer... lxml winning by only a few percent. I must have had an outlier.

Answer (score 0):

Where does it crash? I guess, it's at `soup = ...`. If so, then you might be better off implementing a SAX parser, rather than building the whole DOM in `BeautifulSoup`. Given the strict structure of the HTML source, you might even consider hand-coding to that structure and do something like

```
for line in ...:
    if line.startswith("<td"):
        ...
        td = line.split('">')[1].split('</')[0]
    ...
```

but this will very much depend on how much the HTML page will vary over time. "Real" parsing might be preferable.

**Update:**

After fixing the issue with the `rowspan` in the last line, 1300 display lines (`len(all_tr) == 3465`) are quickly generated as 433 copies of the demo data given by OP. The HTML file size is 1.2MiB then.

The script ran for 2.6s overall, 2.3s in `bs4`, on my machine (i7 4-core Lenovo X230, Ubuntu 14.04), consuming 131 MiB of memory, 127 MiB by `bs4`. A Raspberry Pi 2B needs 64s @ 700 MHz, btw. I was  using `Python 2.7.6` with `bs4 4.2.1` employing the default XML parser. Runtimes measured by `cProfile`, memory consumption by [memory_profiler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). About the `zip()`, we already had a remark...

It would be interesting to learn the environment in which OPs script dies.

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately!) it does not crash on BeautifulSoup initialization. It is a silent crash. Probably because it is running out of memory.

Comment: Referring to the update above, can you give some detail about your environment?

Comment: it is a Intel Core 2 Duo T6670 processor (2.20GHz) with 4Gb of RAM running Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Does not explain your experience. Have you checked Python and BS4 versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd

with open('data.html', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

# parse 1st HTML table to pandas.DataFrame
df = pd.read_html(data, header=0)[0]

# drop unimportant columns
df = df.drop(df.columns[[1, 18]], axis=1).dropna(how='all')

# write the CSV file
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

# print(df)
```

output.csv:

```
Header 1,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5,Header 6,Header 7,Header 8,Header 9,Header 10,Header 11,Header 12,Header 13,Header 14,Header 15,Header 16,Header 17,Header 18,Header 20,Header 21,Header 22,Header 23,Header 24,Header 25,Header 26,Header 27,Header 28,Header 29,Header 30,Header 31,Header 32,Header 33
1.0,18.0,20.0,25.0,23.0,10.0,11.0,24.0,14.0,6.0,2.0,13.0,9.0,5.0,16.0,3.0,Next value indicates number of rows to skip,,XA,15.0,46.0,48.0,25.0,49.0,68.0,10.0,40.0,20.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2.0,23.0,15.0,5.0,4.0,12.0,16.0,20.0,6.0,11.0,19.0,24.0,1.0,9.0,13.0,7.0,Next value indicates number of rows to skip,,XA,184.0,6232.0,81252.0,478188.0,596.3237,1.38895,1000.0,400.0,200.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
3.0,18.0,20.0,25.0,23.0,10.0,11.0,24.0,14.0,6.0,2.0,13.0,9.0,5.0,16.0,3.0,Next value indicates number of rows to skip,,XA,15.0,46.0,48.0,25.0,49.0,68.0,10.0,40.0,20.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

Please let us know how fast/slow it is on your real HTML file.